# Django Changing css for base.html based on model instance field value

Tags: python, django, notifications

I have just built this notification system and it works great. However, I don't want to expect that a user will check the notifications page themselves, and so in order to notify the user that they have a new notification I would like the notification link in the nabber to have different css properties depending on if that user has any notifications that have not been read.

I am a little stuck on this because the html link that should be changed is in my base.html rather than the app. Also, being that it is a notifications system and new notifications are created all the time and being marked read all the time it needs to be able to go through a loop and look at every notification pertaining to the logged in user.

Here is my code, any help would be much appreciated.

Notify app Model:

```
class UserNotification(models.Model):
    fromUser = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user',null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('feed.UserPost',related_name='post')
    toUser = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='user')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    notify_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('notify:user_notifications')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fromUser)
```

Base.html navbar:

```
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Evverest</a>

        <div class="navbar">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_profile' request.user.id %}">
                    {{ request.user.username|capfirst }}
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'notify:user_notifications' %}">
                    Notifications
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:user_list' %}">All Members</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_logout' %}">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_login' %}?next=/">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}?next=/">Register</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

There isn't really a view associated with this right now, let me know if you need to see anything else.

**Second Edit**
Just for clarification, I just want to be able to change the CSS of the notification button in the navbar. Here is picture to show what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: i have a notification system in my website and it use the same model u r using you can read the website code at github [here](https://github.com/mikeGHQ/SetTheCodeProject) if you wan't me to tell you how to do the whole system i can add a link to a post in my blog that teaches  you how

Comment: Sure whats the link

Comment: http://setthecode.pythonanywhere.com/post?id=17

Comment: I followed everything you have in that post and it all makes sense. What I'm not following, however, is since I don't want to have a list in my base template (I have a separate notifications page that displays the list), instead just change the css of the notifications link if the user has any unread notifications (maybe the background would become read instead of blue). Can I do that with what your post says??

Comment: ok i will update the post so you can know if the user viewed the notification or not. please wait : )

Comment: i added this to the post read it again http://setthecode.pythonanywhere.com/post?id=17

Comment: The update you added seems to enable to mark the notification as read, which my system already allows for. What I'm trying to do is simply change the css of the button to show if there is an unread notification. Please see my second edit to the post, I have added a picture to illustrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: simplly use `{%if not seen%}your red icon{% endif %}`

Comment: so this? `{% if notification not read %}not-read{% endif %}`? (my template tag is called `notification `)

Comment: how do you get the notification list? so i can tell how exactly

Comment: In the template tag or the view?

Comment: why you are using a template tag and a view

Comment: I had the view already and then I tried to follow your article and so I added a template tag. I still want to have a separate page to list the notifications, but want the base template css to change to alert the user that they have a  new notification waiting for them

Comment: i used the template tag because my notification appear in the base template, but you have a notification template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158897/discussion-between-mohammed-qudah-and-garrett).